# Creating Your First Http Server in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So guys, am pretty new to node but have covered some ground. I created my first "example" server from [this tutorial](https://blog.risingstack.com/your-first-node-js-http-server/)
but don't understand a few things.
Can anyone explain to me what this

```
 '/'
```

in this line does or point me to some docs?

```
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '/' represents the 'root' route of the application, in other words, the home page.

Contrast that with a '/login' route for example. This particular route would send users to mysite.com/login.

Read more about routing in ExpressJS [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

Comment: @AnandRajput in that case, would you mind accepting the answer? Thanks!